# I want to know if i can use an SQL keyword inside another keyword , like COUNT(DISTINCT(<columnname>))

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

```
SELECT AVG(salary) FROM emp where COUNT(DISTINCT(dept)) > 3 ;
```

Using this query, i want to calculate the average salary of Departments where employee number is more than 3.

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: sql server management

Comment: Note that `distinct` is **not** a function. Putting the column following the keyword between parentheses won't change a thing.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to calculate the average salary of Departments where employee number is more than 3.

As I interpret the question, you want:

```
select dept, avg(salary)
from emp
group by dept
having count(*) > 3;
```

If you want the average across all departments, then it is not clear if you want the average of the department averages.  Or the average of the employees in those departments.  Either way, you need a subquery:

```
select avg(dept_avg) as average_of_department_salaries,
       sum(sum_salary) / sum(num_emp) as employee_average_salary
from (select dept, avg(salary) as dept_avg, count(*) as num_emp, sum(salary) as sum_salary
      from emp
      group by dept
      having count(*) > 3
     ) d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING :

```
SELECT AVG(salary) 
FROM emp 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dept) > 3 ;
```

I am not sure what is it exactly you need but here is a demo of my example and one more example with a function inside a function [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cc64d33e9ffe27cc08b6db5796ac0653)

Above is answer for Oracle. For sqlserver I suggest to use "function inside of function" like this:

```
select avg(tolumn1)
from (select count(salary) as tolumn1
      from emp) A
```

Comment: distinct is not a function

Comment: Where do I say it is ?

Comment: look at your syntax, you'll easily find out where you said it is !!

Comment: It looks like I did.. I have just copy paste the code and changed one keyword... Thanks!

Comment: @fahmi i used the term function in general 
i know its a keyword

Comment: Hi @BLAEZI does my answer help you ? If not I can delete it so others maybe will open it sooner and answer it...

Comment: @VBoka yes man , it did help me ... thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

`Select Avg(E.Salary),D.Department_name from Departments AS D inner join Employee AS E on D.Dept_Id = E.Dept_Id group by Department_name having count(Emp_Id)>3`

The required result for the problem cannot be obtained without a join on Department table and the Employee table. Hence using alias for the two tables with a Group by clause followed by Having clause.